# Join values from two columns with SQL separated by " / "

Tags: sql, join

I need to join columns in one column with the values separated by a dash.
But only if both columns have values, which is not always the case. In this case I only want to move the value and present it alone in the result column.
How do I best achieve this?

[image]

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: `coalesce(col1 || '/' || col2, col1, col2)`

Answer (score 2):

You want string concatenation. A standard way to express this would be:

```
select col1, col2,
    case 
        when col1 is not null and col2 is not null then col1 || '/' || col2
        else coalesce(col1, col2)
    end as result
from mytable
```

`||` is the standard operator for string concatenation - the syntax may vary across databases (but there always is an equivalent operator or function).

Some databases implement `concat_ws()`, and in some databases it does ignore `null` values, which lets you simplify the whole `case` expression as:

```
concat_ws('/', col1, col2) as result
```

An example of a database that supports such syntax is MySQL.

Comment: Postgres also supports `concat_ws()` that way

Answer (score 0):

Just use `case` expression:

```
select case when col1 is not null and col2 is not null then col1 + ' / ' + col2
            when col1 is not null then col1
            when col2 is not null then col2
            else null end
from myTable;
```

Note that string concatenation might differ depeneding on RDBMS, for example in MySql I used `concat(col1, ' / ', col2)` (in the fiddle).

BTW, `/` is not a dash, it is slash (forward slash).

[Sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0c4bcf/3)

Answer (score 0):

Ahhaann!! You can simply use the `trim` function as follows (Oracle example)

```
select trim('/' from col1 || '/' || col2) as result
  from your_Table;
```

`TRIM` function is available in every database.

Answer (score 0):

Several databases support `concat_ws()`, which is the simplest approach:

```
concat_ws('/', column1, column2)
```

In those that don't, you need to use database-specific functions.  A standard SQL construct is:

```
substring('/' || column1 || '/' || column2 from 2)
```